# in Meteor, how can i set up Facebook logins to use the useraccounts:core registration fields?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

i have a Meteor 1.3 app w/ Blaze and Flowrouter. i am using useraccounts:core, with some of the related packages. i have read through the [guide](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md). i am able to log in with Facebook / Google / Instagram / Twitter. i do *not* have account-password enabled, because i want to force users to log in with social media.

what i would like to do is add some registration fields, per the guide:

```
AccountsTemplates.addField({
    _id: "fruit",
    type: "radio",
    displayName: "Preferred Fruit",
    select: [
        {
        text: "Apple",
        value: "aa",
      }, {
        text: "Banana",
        value: "bb",
      }, {
        text: "Carrot",
        value: "cc",
      },
    ],
});
```

i have noticed:

- any fields i add like that do not show up unless i add the accounts-password package
- even though useraccounts:core allows me to (say) "Login with Facebook" 
  and "Register with Facebook", there is no practical difference. i.e. a first login counts as a registration

what i would like is the following:

- if a user does not have an account, "Login with Facebook" does not automatically register them
- i can use the built-in register page and addFields functionality for social media accounts, forcing FB et. al. users to fill out my registration fields

is this possible? as far as i can tell, even if i enabled accounts-password and added my fields, there's no way (using these packages) to force anyone to properly register. they can simply "Login with Facebook" and have an account.

is there something i'm missing about what's available? if not, how have others accomplished what i want to do without scrapping use of these packages and building it all from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

so here's what i've done...

i gave in and added accounts-password in order to get the registration functionality, but disabled logging in with username/password and disabled registering w/ social media. my next step will be to force them to link to a social media account right after registering and logging in.

on the server, i'm using Accounts.validateNewUser() to fail unless there's a password. this allows registration via accounts-password, but disallows OAuth registration. on the client registration screen, i'm using jQuery to delete the DOM nodes in atForm that show the social registration.

also on the server, i'm using Accounts.validateLoginAttempt() to fail if attemptInfo.allowed is false. This captures the case when someone uses social media login for the first time (i.e. attached to no existing account). on the client, using jQuery, i delete the DOM nodes in atForm that show the accounts-ui login on the sign-in page.

it's kinda ugly, but it mostly works. i would like to disallow username/password logging in in Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(), but that is called immediately after Accounts.validateNewUser() and i need the user logged-in so i can force them to link a social media account. i.e. so they can log in the next time. I will do it if i can figure out a way to differentiate between a login associated with registration, and a later login.

i'm open to suggestions for improvements!